# Error : function levenshtein() does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am using levenshtein() function in my SQL script. I am using Postgresql database and client to execute the script. It's throwing an error:

> function levenshtein(character varying, character varying) does not exist.
>   HINT : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I know the common solution to it i.e creating extensions like 'fuzzystrmatch' which I already did and strange thing is that the same script ran smoothly 4 days ago when I created fuzzystrmatch extension in the first place!

Below is my line of code where levenshtein() is used.

```
as $$select (1.0 - levenshtein($1, $2)::real/greatest(length($1), length($2)))::real;$$;
```

Answer (score 17):

This SQL command tells you where the extension is currently installed:

```
SELECT n.nspname
FROM pg_extension e
   JOIN pg_namespace n
      ON e.extnamespace = n.oid
WHERE e.extname = 'fuzzystrmatch';
```

If that not on your `search_path`, your query will not find the function.

To have the extension in a different schema, in the following example `public`, drop and recreate it:

```
DROP EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch SCHEMA public;
```

Comment: Hm.  I ran this sql, and it shows the function is installed in my schema.  However, am still getting the error

Comment: @jrdunson Perhaps "your schema" is not on the `search_path`?

Comment: Hey thanks, but my search path is the schema I'm expecting

Comment: Looks as it gets confused with gis extentions. This worked:
dropped postgis_topology; and postgis; fuzzystrmatch;
set schema <<schema>>
create extension postgis; fuzzystrmatch; tiger_geocoder; and postgis_topology;
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394880/aws-rds-postgresql-9-5-4-extension-postgis-tiger-geocoder-missing-soundex

Comment: @jrdunson Well, if you install the extension in a schema that is on your `search_path`, it will work. Just like I told you.